# Entity framework linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have this piece of code. What i need to do is to exclude `mc_host_class` values that are inside the list.

```
enter  var myList = (from p in db.Full
                      where ( (p.date_reception > begin & p.date_reception < end & !p.mc_host_class.Contains("NULL")) &

                     ( !p.mc_host_class.Contains( (
                            from p2 in db.exclure
                            where (p2.type.Contains("Host"))
                            group p2 by p2.libelle into g
                            select new { libellex = g.Key}).ToList()
                      )))
                      group p by p.mc_host_class into g
                      orderby g.Count() descending
                      select new
                      {
                          hostclassx = g.Key,
                          countx = g.Count()
                      }).ToList().Take(10);
```

Thank you for helping

Comment: What exactly does not work?

Comment: i get underlining under here
                         ( !p.mc_host_class.Contains( (
                                from p2 in db.exclure
                                where (p2.type.Contains("Host"))
                                group p2 by p2.libelle into g
                                select new { libellex = g.Key}).ToList() under !p.mc_host_class and toList()

Comment: Then what does it say?

Comment: cannot convert anonymous type# to string

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question, I think this could help you:

```
(!(
    from p2 in db.exclure
    where (p2.type.Contains("Host")
    group p2 by p2.libelle into g
    select new { libellex = g.Key}
).ToList().Contains(p.mc_host_class))
```

List1.Contains(value1) return a bool if a value1 is in List1, but you used it like value1.Contains(List1).

[image]

Comment: they tell me Contains(Anonymoustype# 1) has unvalid arguments

Comment: @drexdrex I added a screenshot

Comment: sorry i could not see it , company uses proxy , i managed to solve it thanks a lot for helping (y)